Is there a publicly-searchable database of RCA members (or other way to find out if a given rabbi is a member)?
Is there a way to find out whether a particular rabbi is a member of the Rabbinical Council of America?  Is there a searchable database of members, or some other method?

office@rabbis.org

The Rabbinical Council of America (RCA) website has a searchable database of some of its members; it does not appear to list all members:
https://rabbis.org/meet-our-chaverim/

I think that's only those who've chosen to put a profile online. There are several card-carrying RCA member rabbis I couldn't find there.

You are probably correct. The page/site doesn't specify if the rabbis listed are the entire membership, or some subset. The page header reads  "Meet Our Chaverim" and the search box "Search Our Rabbis". Since I do not know how many members there are vs how many are listed I have edited my answer accordingly.
